# Javascript. Как поменять background-image?

Tags: javascript

Всем привет! Хочу на чистом js поменять background у блока. Есть такой код:

```
.block{
     background-image: url(img/img1.jpg);
 }


var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
btn.addEventListener('click', function(){changeBgImg();});

var block = document.getElementById('block');

function changeBgImg(){
    block.style.backgroundImage = 'img/img2.jpg'
}
```

Но почему-то такой код не работает, background не меняется. Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Подключи Jquery и не мучайся

Comment: jquery - для слабаков)))))))))

Comment: А ты у нас гуру програмист да?)печатаешь на простом блокноте не бось )))))

Comment: Бывает)) Так есть какие нибудь варианты ?

Comment: block.style.backgroundImage = "url('img/img2.jpg')"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Пишите также, как и в `css`, т.е. вместе с `url`:

```js
var block = document.getElementById('block');

function changeBgImg(){
    block.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://cs7062.vk.me/c540107/v540107359/2729/fYQlS_23QdA.jpg')";
}

changeBgImg();
```

```css
#block {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="block">222</div>
```

Comment: Всем спасибо за помощь))))